# Access a portion of a remote file using curl

Tags: php, curl

I need to download a remote file to my server,
I found a way to download using curl. fopen.. are not working as url file access is disabled.
I just want to download a few MB of the the files which will be 100mb to a few Gb in size.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can download Few MB of a large file using `CURLOPT_RANGE`

Example

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://link-to-large-file');

/**
 * First 2MB of that file 
 */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE, '0-2000');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result
```

You can also combine this with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` where you can create a custom callback to write specific section of the file